# How to execute deno without strict mode ? Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'list' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, deno

Getting error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'list' has already been declared

**Can we execute deno without strict mode?**

Searched online but there is no clear documentation.

Comment: Why not just fix the error, instead of looking for legacy sloppy mode?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way, since Deno uses `ES6 Modules`, and **module code is always run in strict mode.**

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

> ECMAScript 2015 introduced JavaScript modules and therefore a 3rd way
>   to enter strict mode.  The entire contents of JavaScript modules are
>   automatically in strict mode, with no statement needed to initiate it.